# Get the highest value of tuple?

Tags: haskell

If I have ha list of tuple like `[("candy",3), ("icecream",2), ("meat",6)]`. How do I get the tuple with the highest number?

Otherwise, Would a recursive function that collects all the numbers be of help? If so, how would I do?

Comment: You should perhaps considert folding the list.

Comment: Is there anything you tried that failed?

Comment: What would you do to determine the highest number of `[3, 2, 5]`?

Comment: Try [`maximumBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy).

Comment: Could you give me a headsup on how to begin?

Comment: If I use the maximum function it will only look on the first item in the tuple. I want it to only look at the number

Comment: What if there are two tuples with the maximum number as second item?

Answer (score 4):

Use `Data.List.maximumBy` with `Data.Ord.comparing` to create the comparison function to use in place of the `Ord` instance for tuples.

```
>>> maximum [("zoo", 1), ("ant", 10)]
("zoo", 1)  -- Because ("zoo", 1) > ("ant", 10), because "zoo" > "ant"
>>> maximumBy (comparing snd) [("zoo", 1), ("ant", 10)]
("ant", 10)  -- Because 10 > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First attempt:

```
maxTupleL :: [(a, Int)] -> (a, Int)
maxTupleL (t:[]) = t
maxTupleL (t:ts) = maxT t (maxTupleL ts)

maxT :: (a, Int) -> (a, Int) -> (a, Int)
maxT (v1, n) (v2, m) = if (n > m)
                       then (v1, n)
                       else (v2, m)
```

---

Maybe you should try using a fold but you need to handle the empty list case (which I don't handle), the if-clause could be changed, as I said this is a first attempt.
Please modify the title of the question, It doesn't match the question itself.